# VichUploaderBundle twig Unable to get filename property value: "image"

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I´m having problems using VichUploaderBundle. Uploads files correctly, but when I write

```
<td><img src="<img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(entity, 'image') }}" alt="{{ entity.nombre }}" />"</td>
```

to display an uploaded picture, I have this error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to get filename property value: "image"") in SuperlineaBundle:Instruccion:index.html.twig at line 21.
```

I tried to get helper on the controller and it works:

```
$helper = $this->container->get('vich_uploader.templating.helper.uploader_helper');
$path = $helper->asset($entities[0], 'image');
ladybug_dump( $path );
```

Displays: string(25) "/images/uploads/video.png"

Any help or clue?

This is my entity: http://pastebin.com/d8X72zK4
This is my config:

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    twig: true
    gaufrette: false # set to true to enable gaufrette support
    storage: vich_uploader.storage.file_system
    mappings:
        uploads:
            uri_prefix: /images/uploads
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/uploads
            namer: ~ # specify a file namer service id for this entity, null default
            directory_namer: ~ # specify a directory namer service id for this entity, null default
            delete_on_remove: true # determines whether to delete file upon removal of entity
            inject_on_load: true # determines whether to inject a File instance upon load
        pdfs:
            uri_prefix: /images/pdf
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/pdf
            namer: ~ # specify a file namer service id for this entity, null default
            directory_namer: ~ # specify a directory namer service id for this entity, null default
            delete_on_remove: true # determines whether to delete file upon removal of entity
            inject_on_load: true # determines whether to inject a File instance upon load
```

And this is my twig template:
...

```
{% for entity in entities %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ path('instruccion_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.id }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ entity.nombre }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.foto }}<img src="<img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(entity, 'image') } }" alt="{{ entity.nombre }}" />"</td>
            <td>{{ entity.video }}</td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ path('instruccion_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">show</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ path('instruccion_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">edit</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct this line

```
<td>{{ entity.foto }}<img src="<img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(entity, 'image') } }" alt="{{ entity.nombre }}" />"</td>
```

you have double img tag

Answer (score 6):

I too had this problem. I was caused by the way my entity was loaded. The entity I was displaying was a property of another entity.

Details:

https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/issues/109

https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/issues/28

I hope this helps someone!

Thanks,
 Gav

Answer (score 1):

That will happen if the target field has a null value, you need to test it before calling vich_uploader_asset. Try this:

```
<td>
{# foto is the uploader target field in your entity #}
{% if entity.foto %}
<img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(entity, 'image') }}" alt="{{ entity.nombre }}" />
{% else %}
{# display nothing, or use a generic image #}
<img src='no-img.png' alt='{{ entity.nombre }}' />
{% endif %}
</td>
```